# Faster/Easier Blackberry Programming?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Is there an easier way to program on the Blackberry platform?

Let me be a bit more specific.

Is there an easier/faster way to test my software on the BB without waiting for the emulator to restart every time I make a change in the code?

Constantly waiting on the emulator to startup is a real pain.

Any suggestions are welcome, as well as any general tips for faster/easier devlopment on the BB.

Thanks.

Comment: get used to it  :)
seriously though, it is just as backwards as it feels...
If a class size changes, you will get bitten by the restart, if you're using a RIM provided OS specific sim package, it will restart...  If you're using a generic simulator 5.0 + it will typically work with a relaunch of your debug session, not restarting the simulator...
Anything pre 5.0 is just that way.
Everyone who works with this platform will agree -- it is not the most dev friendly environment around -- nor is it the worst, but man is it painful  :)

Comment: @Dan you can post this comment as an answer of this question.

Comment: @Vivart, thx was considering it already lol

Comment: @Dan yeah +1 for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get used to it :) seriously though, it is just as backwards as it feels... If a class size changes, you will get bitten by the restart, if you're using a RIM provided OS specific sim package, it will restart... If you're using a generic simulator 5.0 + it will typically work with a relaunch of your debug session, not restarting the simulator... Anything pre 5.0 is just that way. Everyone who works with this platform will agree -- it is not the most dev friendly environment around -- nor is it the worst, but man is it painful :)